# wide column with multi-columns

Tags: tables

I am trying to make wide column in two-columns format.
my table has multi-columns too and there is gap in the last column. how can I get rid of it?
Also it's in one column know. how can I make it wide?

[image]

```
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{wide table.}
\begin{tabular}{lrr|rr|rr|rr|rr|cc}
\toprule
() & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{VGG16} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Inceptionv3} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{ResNet50} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{InceptionResnetv2} \\ 
() & \multicolumn{1}{l}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{64}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{64} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{32} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{64} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{64}  \\ 
\midrule
a & 1.2 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 3.5 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.0   \\
b & 12.8 & 3.8 & 4.9 & 5.9 & 1.4 & 0.1 & 4.8 & 1.5  \\
c & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 3.8 & 2.5 \\
ç & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 3.8 & 2.5 \\
d & 14.0 & 17.3 & 22.2 & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.9 & 1.1   \\
e & 7.9 & 21.1 & 27.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.8  \\
f & 3.0 & 22.3 & 28.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
g & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
h & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
i & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
j & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
l & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
m & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
n & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
o & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
p & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
q & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
r & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
s & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
t & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
uv & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
x & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
y & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
z & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{t:props}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! The text `InceptionResnetv2` is too wide. You could typeset it in two rows. E.g. `\multicolumn{ 2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
Inception\\ Resnetv2
\end{tabular}}` is an option.

Comment: I see. How can I do that?

Comment: Use e.g. `\multicolumn{ 2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
Inception\\ Resnetv2
\end{tabular}}` for that entry. You may also want to consider removing the vertical lines.

Comment: thanks. do you have an idea how can I make the table wide?

Comment: If you want to fill a certain amount of space, you could use the `tabularx` package. Also the `cc` in `\begin{tabular}{lrr|rr|rr|rr|rr|cc}` are unnecessary.

Comment: @Nouf -- i have split the first row into 2 parts upper and lower for symmetry -- otherwise because of the last column entry it seems to hanging towards one side--unbalanced--rest i think is self explanatory

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
    \definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

    \newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
    \newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering\caption{wide table.}
        \begin{tabular}{lab|ab|ab|ab|ab|ab}
            \toprule \rowcolor{LightCyan}
            () & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} VGG\\16 \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Inception\\v3 \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} ResNet\\ 50 \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Inception\\ Resnetv2 \end{tabular}} \\ 
            () & \multicolumn{1}{c}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{64}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{64} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{32} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{64} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{64}  \\ 
            \midrule
            a & 1.2 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 3.5 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.0   \\
            b & 12.8 & 3.8 & 4.9 & 5.9 & 1.4 & 0.1 & 4.8 & 1.5  \\
            c & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 3.8 & 2.5 \\
            ç & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 3.8 & 2.5 \\
            d & 14.0 & 17.3 & 22.2 & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.9 & 1.1   \\
            e & 7.9 & 21.1 & 27.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.8  \\
            f & 3.0 & 22.3 & 28.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
            g & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            h & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            i & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            j & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            l & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            m & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            n & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            o & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            p & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            q & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            r & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            s & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            t & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            uv & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            x & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            y & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            z & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{t:props}

    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**

for horizontal spread of the table you can play with adding in the preamble

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
```

and remove verticals for visual appeal `{||||||}`

**the result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1. Since you're using color (and grayscale) to provide visual formatting, you can omit the horizontal rules

Comment: true that -- and your +1 could be on the up pointing triangle -- hahaha -- just joking

Comment: I've gone ahead and inserted an additional screenshot, immediately below your second screenshot. I'll let you decide if you wish to delete the older one -- or the newer one. :-)

Comment: your table still looks better --IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You asked in a comment,

> do you have an idea how can I make the table wide?

Some suggestions and observations, in no particular order:

- When you say that you would like to make the table "wide", I assume you mean, "as wide as the textblock". If this assumption is correct, I suggest you use a 9-column `tabularx` environment. The first column should presumably be typeset raggedright while the 8 data columns should be typeset centered.
- To permit equal column widths across the 8 data columns, you need to permit line breaking in at least one of the header cells. The code below shows how this may be set up.
- The material in the first cell will get line-wrapped automatically, as needed.
- I think your readers will appreciate it if the numbers are aligned on their respective decimal markers. This may be achieved by using the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' and '\RaggedRight' macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\mCC[2]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}
\caption{wide table.}\label{t:props}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{4}{T{2.1}} T{1.1} T{1.1} T{2.1} T{1.1} @{}}
\toprule
() & \mCC{C}{VGG16} 
   & \mCC{C}{Inception v3} 
   & \mCC{C}{ResNet 50} 
   & \mCC{C@{}}{Inception Resnetv2} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
() & \mC{32} & \mC{64}  & \mC{32} & \mC{64} 
   & \mC{32} & \mC{64}  & \mC{32} & \multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{64} \\ 
\midrule
a &  1.2 &  0.1 &  0.2 &  3.5 & 0.4 & 0.0 &  0.2 & 0.0 \\
b & 12.8 &  3.8 &  4.9 &  5.9 & 1.4 & 0.1 &  4.8 & 1.5 \\
c & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 &  0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 &  3.8 & 2.5 \\
ç & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 &  0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 &  3.8 & 2.5 \\
d & 14.0 & 17.3 & 22.2 &  0.7 & 0.8 & 0.0 &  0.9 & 1.1 \\
e &  7.9 & 21.1 & 27.0 &  0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 &  0.3 & 0.8 \\
f &  3.0 & 22.3 & 28.6 &  0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 &  0.0 & 0.0 \\
g & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
h & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
i & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
j & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
l & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
m & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
n & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
o & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
p & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
q & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
r & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
s & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
t & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
uv& 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
x & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
y & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
z & 54.6 & 75.0 & 96.4 & 10.6 & 2.9 & 0.2 & 10.1 & 5.9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how is the font and appearance of your table better -- though in the preamble there is nothing additional compared to my answer below

Comment: @jsbibra - Please clarify what you mean by "better" font and appearance. (You don't mean the resolution of the screenshots, do you?)

Comment: compare your table with mine -- what is the difference due?  is it resolution-- becauae its is not standalone

Comment: @jsbibra - Our workflows for generating screenshots may differ consirably. I'm on a MacBook Air with MacOS 10.15.4 "Catalina", and I create screenshots (in png format) via Command-Shift-"4". Comparing the structures of our tables, an obvious difference is in the use of colored rows and columns. Another difference is in the use or non-use of `\cmidrule` directives to tie together the cells in the first and second rows of the header. Still another difference pertains to how the numbers are typeset: centered in your case, aligned on the decimal markers in mine.

Comment: i take a screenshot with evernote -- my windows 10 desktop and macbook air both have evernote-- but what i was referring was not the details but the visual impact of your table when compared with other tables in stack exchange other answers--your table stands out when you lean back and look at it-- just wondering how its so

Comment: @jsbibra - Would you like me to create screenshots from your answers and insert them instead of the existing ones? That way, you could decide if it's the screenshot software that makes the difference.

Comment: please go ahead - lets see the difference

Answer (score 2):

For grouping columns you can insert empty columns between their pairs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\caption{wide table.}
    \label{t:props}
\sisetup{table-format=2.1, table-column-width=2em}
\begin{tabular}{l SS c SS c S[table-format=1.1]S[table-format=1.1] c SS[table-format=1.1]}
   \toprule
    & \mcc[2]{VGG16} &&  \mcc[2]{Inceptionv3} 
        &&  \mcc[2]{ResNet50} && \mcc[2]{\makecell[b]{Inception\\Resnetv2}}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    \cmidrule{5-6}
    \cmidrule{8-9}
    \cmidrule{11-12}
    & \mcc{32} & \mcc{64}  && \mcc{32} & \mcc{64} 
        && \mcc{32} & \mcc{64} && \mcc{32} & \mcc{64}     \\
    \midrule
a   & 1.2  &  0.1 &&  0.2 &  3.5 && 0.4 & 0.0 &&  0.2 & 0.0   \\
b   & 12.8 &  3.8 &&  4.9 &  5.9 && 1.4 & 0.1 &&  4.8 & 1.5  \\
c   & 15.5 & 10.4 && 13.4 &  0.4 && 0.3 & 0.0 && 3.8 & 2.5 \\
ç   & 15.5 & 10.4 && 13.4 &  0.4 && 0.3 & 0.0 && 3.8 & 2.5 \\
d   & 14.0 & 17.3 && 22.2 &  0.7 && 0.8 & 0.0 && 0.9 & 1.1   \\
e   &  7.9 & 21.1 && 27.0 &  0.0 && 0.0 & 0.0 && 0.3 & 0.8  \\
f   &  3.0 & 22.3 && 28.6 &  0.0 && 0.0 & 0.0 && 0.0 & 0.0 \\
g   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
h   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
i   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
j   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
l   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
m   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
n   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
o   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
p   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
q   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
r   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
s   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
t   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
uv  & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
x   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
y   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
z   & 54.6 & 75.0 && 96.4 & 10.6 && 2.9 & 0.2 && 10.1 & 5.9  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]